# in a nested array indices in Ruby

Tags: ruby

in a nested a array that is going to be used as a grid is there an easir
way of checking weather the places above and below are empty or is the only way alot of if ,elsif  statements

i.e

```
             if maze[i][j-1].to_i == index
               maze[i][j-1] = ">"
               #down
             elsif maze[i+1][j].to_i == index
               maze[i+1][j] = ">"
              # UP
            elsif maze[i-1][j].to_i == index
              maze[i-1][j] = ">"
              #right
            elsif  maze[i][j+1].to_i == index
               maze[i][j+1] = ">"
            end
```

Comment: The posted code is incomplete. You must also take care to not pass the array bounds. If `j == 0`, `j-1` is outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Not much easier, but a cleaner way to do this would be to make some boolean check methods like

def up?, def down? etc.. which encapsulate all the logic you are checking in the if/elsif.

Something like:

```
if down?
 do the thing
etc..
```

You can also try using a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just build an array of offsets and test for matches:

```
hi, hj = [ [-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1] ].find do |di, dj|
  maze[i + di][j + dj].to_i == index
end

if (hi && hj)
  maze[i + hi][j + hj] = '>'
end
```

If you're doing a lot of tests it makes sense to define that as a content:

```
UDLR = [ [-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1] ]
```

Then that structure is recycled for each call.